# Is this behavior of Solve intended?

Tags: equation-solving

Assume we have the following set of equations and we're looking for a solution for `c`:

```
a+b+c+d+e=65
a=b+5
c=b-5
c=d+5
e=d-5
```

A first approach may look like so:

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65, c]
(*{{c->-a-b-d-e+65}}*)
```

Adding additional information, however, returns an empty solution:

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5, c]
(*{}*)
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5 && c == b - 5 && 
 c == d + 5 && e == d - 5, c]
(*{}*)
```

Once one is specifying all variables a proper solution can be obtained:

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5 && c == b - 5 && 
 c == d + 5 && e == d - 5, {a, b, c, d, e}]
(*{{a->23,b->18,c->13,d->8,e->3}}*)
```

My question: why do we get a partial solution with one equation and one variable, but no solution if we provide more information but still only look for one variable, but obtain a full solution if we're searching for all variables using all available information?
I would have expected to gain a "better" solution, i.e.:

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5, c]
(*{{c->-2b-d-e+60}}*)
(*{{c->-2a-d-e+70}}*)
```

Comment: @Bill Thanks for your comment but that's known to me. The question was why `Solve` behaves that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the behavior is intended and it is documented:

[Solve >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html):

- Solve *gives generic solutions only. **Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed.** Other solutions that are only conditionally valid are expressed as* ConditionalExpression *objects.*

And [Solve >> Options >> MaxExtraConditions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html):

- *By default, no solutions requiring extra conditions are produced.*
- *The default setting,* MaxExtraConditions -> 0, *gives no solutions requiring conditions.*

The first example under `MaxExtraConditions` in the documentation center:

```
Solve[a == 0 && x == 0, x]
```

> {}

OP's example with a non-default setting for the option `MaxExtraConditions`:

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5, c, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> {{c -> ConditionalExpression[60 - 2 b - d - e, a == 5 + b]}}

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the `MaxExtraConditions`.

Answer (score 0):

Either specify a second variable for which to solve

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5, {c, #}] & /@ {a, b}

(* {{{c -> 60 - 2 b - d - e, a -> 5 + b}}, {{c -> 70 - 2 a - d - e, 
   b -> -5 + a}}} *)
```

or specify a variable to be eliminated

```
Solve[a + b + c + d + e == 65 && a == b + 5, c, {#}] & /@ {a, b}

(* {{{c -> 60 - 2 b - d - e}}, {{c -> 70 - 2 a - d - e}}} *)
```